# using libdrizzle as an async mysql connector

Tags: c++, mysql, performance, asynchronous, libdrizzle

I'm interested in using `libdrizzle` as a generic asynchronous-capable connector for mysql db for a c++ application (actually as a backend for [hiberlite](http://code.google.com/p/hiberlite/)). Since early this year libdrizzle is no longer a separate project and its merged in the same [drizzle project](https://launchpad.net/drizzle), so installing as a separate dependency (unrelated to the rest of drizzle) might have become slightly more complex.

I'm wondering if people has used this library for interfacing to MySql or MariaDB, probably make some mickey mouse benchmarks to have a rough idea how it stands relative to the synchronous default driver.

Also, comments on difficulties to install, setup, pitfalls (the documentation is essentially nonexistent) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I added a bounty on this question because I do not like the MySQL client library API nor the license. The lack of documentation for libdrizzle is horrible. I was trying to find out if it supports [multiple result sets for prepared CALL statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-call-statements.html) or prepared statements with placeholders but I could not find the answer anywhere... I could spend the time to find it out from the source code if I was convinced that librizzle is a good choice.

Comment: Obviously libdrizzle is not very popular as nobody answered even though there was a bounty. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at ngx_drizzle ([drizzle-nginx-module](https://github.com/chaoslawful/drizzle-nginx-module)) at github.

From module description:

> This is an nginx upstream module integrating libdrizzle into Nginx in a non-blocking and streamming way.
>
> Essentially it provides a very efficient and flexible way for nginx internals to access MySQL, Drizzle, as well as other RDBMS's that support the Drizzle or MySQL wired protocol. Also it can serve as a direct REST interface to those RDBMS backends.
>
> If you're using MySQL, then MySQL 5.0 ~ 5.5 is required. We're not sure if MySQL 5.6+ work; reports welcome!